# Scale a canvas inside a templated usercontrol

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0

I created a templated usercontrol from a button in order to use common states etc. What I dont get is how to scale a canvas inside the template. I created a little drawing with lines but they do not scale/transform with the control when I use it. 
Most interesting would be if that is possible using xaml element binding (I am playing with SL3).

Regards Mario

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Grid and set it's Height and Width to Auto.  If yo addi items to the rows and columns and they are all set to stretch the stuff nside the grid will automatically resize.  Not sure if that is what you are asking but that is what comes off the top of my head.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that the drawing is in a canvas